# How to use the shell_plus (iPython) console in PyCharm?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm, ipython

I'm learning to develop in Django and I'm using PyCharm on my project and I would like to use the iPython console in it.

iPython launches, this is not the issue.

The issue is that when I launch iPython from the console, all my models and other utils classes are imported.

This is what happens when I launch the `python3 manage.py shell_plus` command:

```py
# Shell Plus Model Imports
from app.models.models import Model1, Model2, Model3
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission, User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
# Shell Plus Django Imports
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models import Avg, Case, Count, F, Max, Min, Prefetch, Q, Sum, When, Exists, OuterRef, Subquery
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
/myproject/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py:226: UserWarning: IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved
  warn("IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved")
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul 23 2019, 18:02:54) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.13.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:
```

Meanwhile when I start the Python Console in PyCharm, no import has been made and I have to manually import all my models. Here is what happens in the PyCharm Python Console:

```py
/home/user/myproject/env/bin/python /snap/pycharm-community/188/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --port=33543
/home/user/myproject/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py:226: UserWarning: IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved
  warn("IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved")
import sys, django
print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul 23 2019, 18:02:54) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
In[2]:
```

Obviously, a command is executed on the shell_plus command which is not on the PyCharm console.

And here are the versions used.

```
Ubuntu = 18.04 LTS
python = 3.7.4
iPython = 7.13.0
Django = 3.0.5
PyCharm = 2019.3.4 Community
```

Thank you for your help I you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can run custom django commands on pycharm using `Ctrl + ALT + R` or by menu `Tools -> Run manage.py tasks`

Comment: I don't have this option in PyCharm 2019.3.4

Do you also know which script I should use to call shell_plus ? Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: are you using community version or professional version? as this option is only available in professional version. sorry, forget to mention it before

Comment: The community version. Yes, sorry. I forgot they are two versions of the IDE.
So, there is any other way to use iPython's shell in the Python Console ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[I found this online and works well (with autoreload)](https://gist.github.com/DoonDoony/3fd7689bbbc40e3b779f36b765052f27)

NOTE: This only works if you are pretend to using `Django Console` feature in Pycharm

Paste codes below into `Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Django Console > Starting Script`

```
# requirements: `django_extensions`, `IPython`
import sys
import django

from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
from django_extensions.management.notebook_extension import load_ipython_extension

print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
print('Django %s' % django.get_version())

sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])
if 'setup' in dir(django):
    django.setup()
ipython = get_ipython()
load_ipython_extension(ipython)

# NOTE: If you don't use the autoreload feature, don't paste the three lines below
load_ipython_extension(ipython)
ipython.extension_manager.load_extension('autoreload')
ipython.magics_manager.registry['AutoreloadMagics'].autoreload('2')
```